# SignedXML class equal to visual C++?

Tags: c++, xml

Are there have any class equal to SignedXML visual in C++ (I mean not dependency on .net framework)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can digitally sign XML from a Windows C++ app using [libxml](http://xmlsoft.org) and [xmlsec](http://www.aleksey.com/xmlsec). You will probably also need [openssl](http://www.openssl.org) and [libxslt](http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT).

It can take a bit of time to get them compiled with settings compatible with your app, but once they are compiling and linking they work OK.